# Eric has got 1 sum wrong

Tags: puzzle, word-problem

Eric has got 3 sum wrong each time he exactly pressed one wrong key

\begin{align}
5+3+2 & =317 \\
25+36 &=900 \\
8+8+2 &=3 \\
\end{align}

can you work out which key he actually pressed

Comment: The first could be repaired either as $5+312=317$ or as $5+3+2=3+7$; how is one to know?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: While I share your misgivings about this question, it seems to be calculator-based. So the wrong keypress must presumably occur to the left of the $=$ sign.

Comment: God! Eric must be this annoying kid who broke my calculator! :)

Answer (score 3):

By replacing exactly one character for each sum with another we have: For the equation $5+3+2 = 317$ Eric should type $5 + 312$ (thanks to Andy's kind detection); for the equation $25 + 36 = 900$ Eric should type $25 \times 36$; for the equation $8+8+2 = 3$ Eric should type $8  \div 8 + 2$.

I would say your problem may be stated more clearly such as "For each sum Eric pressed exactly one wrong key", which would make it mathematically precise.

Comment: The question gives $5+3+2=317$, so the solution would be $5+312=317$

Comment: @AndyI It could be; however, the sole requirement is that exactly one character can be changed. So... :)

Comment: But my point is that in the original version of the first sum you have removed a character before beginning to solve it

Comment: @AndyI Ha, thank you; just found that I was mistaken the sum. :)

Answer (score 1):

$5+312=317, \quad 25 \cdot 36=900, \quad 8/8+2=3$ so $1,\times,/$ are the right keys.